What could cause 3 sticks of RAM to all stop working at the same time?
While the solution seems clear (throw away RAM and buy new one) I would like to understand what happened here:
I have a PC with a ~1 month old B650M motherboard with a AMD Ryzen 9 7900.
RAM (4x32Gb) was scavenged from a lenovo computer. The lenovo PC became unusuable after a failed repair attempt but RAM seemed ok.
I used the new PC with the full 128Gb of RAM for about a month. Yesterday, the PC wouldn't turn on after restarting.
Usually the first thing I see on the monitor is the bitlocker password (even before UEFI) which wouldn't show. The motherboard has LEDs indicating different components and the one next to 'RAM' was shining red.
The only way I found to get the computer back on was to use 1 specific RAM stick in 1 specific position (the 'A2' position):

When I use that particular working RAM stick in any other position, I'm unable to turn the PC on which I guess makes sense as it says 'first' as can be seen on the picture above.
Any of the other 3 RAM sticks won't work in the A1 position.
It seems that the 3 RAM sticks are broken but it's just hard to believe that all 3 RAM sticks stopped working simultaneously after a normal PC restart.
I am confident that at least >90Gb of RAM were used ~2 weeks ago when I checked with Windows task manager indicating that all 4 sticks seem to have been in use.
I had 2 questions:

Is it expected that a single RAM stick would only work in the A2 position? In other words, is there also a problem with the motherboard?
Any ideas what can happen to destroy 3 RAM sticks simultaneously? Any other things you like to test/do before giving up on the RAM?


According to the manual, the second stick has to go in slot B2. Putting sticks in A2 and A1 will not work.

right A&B is the pairing; the numbers are the groups, and by  the image, the pair A2&B2 need to be populated first.

@doneal24, or first stick can also go to B2: 'When installing a single memory module, we recommend that you install it in the DDR5_A2 or DDR5_B2 socket.'
It seems there's also a problem with the motherboard as only one stick in B2 doesn't work either. Thanks for motivating me to check the manual more carefully.

Its possible (if unlikely) that when the PC tried to boot there was some sort of power spike caused by either a faulty power supply or a faulty motherboard that damaged either the RAM sticks themselves, or the system memory controller in the CPU. It is also just as likely that the motherboard itself has some defect or problem causing this - it could have been caused by a lot of things.
As for ways to try and troubleshoot this further... I would try to clear the CMOS first. If this didn't work, then I would be cleaning the RAM sticks pads with isopropyl alcohol. Not likely to fix, but worth a shot. Last ditch effort, I would be trying to get a hold of another system with DDR5 slots and try them on that. If they don't work in a completely different system, they are almost certainly dead.
(As a side note, I would be checking for a BIOS update before giving up on the board - I've had BIOS updates fix/break seemingly random things on a motherboard, nof a bad idea if your experiencing issues)
